AWUS036NHA won't connect to Kali Linux
I have tried to download the driver from the qca/open-ath9k-firmware, after running
make touchtools


It passed 182/183, the 1 Fail is the tsprintf.
I've tried USB setting configuration and set it to USB 2.0.
I can't see no adapter connected to the Linux when running the lsusb.
I even tried make -k.

Again the error is in the MakeFile 39th line after running
make -C target_firmware


The instructions are available on the manufacturer's website. The chipset is supported already and you just need to install the appropriate firmware from the Kali repository
sudo apt install firmware-atheros

